# How do I convert a symbolic GtkIconSize to an integer size in pixels?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, lgi

I'm updating a GTK+ program, trying to replace all instances of the "stock icons" using "stock ids" to icons using the "icon-name" property. One place that I am a bit confused is how to get the size of an icon.

I have some code that uses the [gtk_render_icon_pixbuf](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.16/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-render-icon-pixbuf) function to obtain a pixbuf from an image with a stock icon:

```lua
if image.storage_type == 'STOCK' then
    return image:render_icon_pixbuf(image.stock, image.icon_size)
end
```

Now I want to make the equivalent of this code for images that use icon_name instead of stock ids. I tried using the [gtk_icon_theme_load_icon](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.16/GtkIconTheme.html#gtk-icon-theme-load-icon) function:

```lua
if image.storage_type == 'ICON_NAME' then
   local icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
   return icon_theme:load_icon(image.icon_name, image.icon_size, 0, nil)
```

However, the icon size comes out wrong (its always the smallest icon size available). I think its because the `icon-size` property is a symbolic value in the [GtkIconSize](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.16/gtk3-Themeable-Stock-Images.html#GtkIconSize) enumeration while gtk_icon_theme_load_icon expects an icon size in pixels.

Is there a way to convert a GtkIconSize to a value in pixels?

Or maybe should I should specify my icon sizes with some other property instead of `icon-size`?

Comment: I don't know how lgi exposes this, but `gtk_icon_size_lookup()`.

Comment: @andlabs: thanks! Thats exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`gtk_icon_size_lookup`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Themeable-Stock-Images.html#gtk-icon-size-lookup) function to convert a symbolic icon size to a length in pixels.

In lgi it can be called like this:

```lua
local width, height = Gtk.icon_size_lookup(image.icon_size)
```